# Content-type does not get updated although present in the postman request

Tags: postman, load-testing, k6

Note: The postman request works fine

I have done the following:

1. Run the postman-to-k6 command : `postman-to-k6 loadTest.postman_collection.json -o k6-script.js`
2. Run the k6 command with the http-debug flag to run the command `k6 run --out csv=test_results.csv k6-script.js --http-debug="full"`

```
// Auto-generated by the postman-to-k6 converter
export let options = { maxRedirects: 4 };

const Request = Symbol.for("request");
postman[Symbol.for("initial")]({
  options
});

export default function() {
  postman[Request]({
    name: "Campaigns",
    id: "189fa369-87c7-4dcb-bf9d-e812d4efd6e8",
    method: "POST",
    address: "https://api.beta.detail-page.journeys.a2z.com/graphql",
    data:
      '{"query":"\\n        query campaigns($projectId: ID!) {\\n            campaigns(projectId: $projectId) {\\n                id\\n                createdAt\\n                createdBy\\n                typeId\\n                originalPodData\\n                useReactAppUrl\\n            }\\n        }\\n        ","variables":{"projectId":"ghost:PublishTest 2:US"}}',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      identitytoken: <Backend-JWT-Token>
    },
    auth(config, Var) {
      const address = new URI(config.address);
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        protocol: address.protocol(),
        hostname: address.hostname(),
        port: address.port(),
        path: address.path() + address.search(),
        body: config.data,
        region: "us-west-2",
        service: <Service-Name>
      };
      const credential = {
        accessKeyId: <accessKey-ID>,
        secretAccessKey: <Secret-key>,
        sessionToken: <Session-token>
      };
      const signed = aws4.sign(options, credential);
      const [path, query = ""] = signed.path.split("?");
      config.address = new URI()
        .protocol(address.protocol())
        .hostname(signed.hostname)
        .path(path)
        .query(query)
        .toString();
      Object.assign(config.headers, signed.headers);
    }
  });
  });
}
```

INFO[0004] Request:

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: api.beta.detail-page.journeys.a2z.com
User-Agent: k6/0.40.0 (https://k6.io/)
Content-Length: 354
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAVGC47R5TZOZXHHNM/20221025/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=9dceffc3e3376fd6f9b860025ce9a82454f740bd189ffa8da3c0a6d8d83e230f
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Identitytoken: <Identity-token>
X-Amz-Date: 20221025T200827Z
X-Amz-Security-Token: <Security-token>
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

```
INFO[0004] Response:
HTTP/2.0 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 61
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 20:08:27 GMT
Etag: W/"3d-hTSca7jJI4XwK3C0Li5aF8JIkvc"
X-Amz-Apigw-Id: ak9JUEu-PHcFefQ=
X-Amzn-Remapped-Connection: close
X-Amzn-Remapped-Content-Length: 61
X-Amzn-Remapped-Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 20:08:27 GMT
X-Amzn-Requestid: bee58104-704c-4cb0-9ec4-399e6f69450d
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-6358423b-5dc39ed81536364944f6bd11
X-Powered-By: Express
```

POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?  group= iter=0 request_id=ad10989c-1023-46c9-5f34-e381a7d5795b scenario=default source=http-debug vu=1

Comment: What prevents you from manually writing the k6 code? (I don't know why data and some headers are not set correctly with the auto-converted postman/k6 code …)

Comment: You are right I ended up figuring out that they are not passing in the headers correctly to the aws4 api, so fixed it with that

Comment: Dharight, if you already fixed it, can you provide an answer to your own question (and accept this answer)? That will help future visitors find a solution if they encounter a similar problem.